# How to change woocommerce catalog ordering for certain products conditionally?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following function to order woocommerce products on product category pages:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', function($args){

if ( !is_product_category() ) return $args;

set_query_var('meta_query',[
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'stock_status_clause' => [ 'key' => '_stock_status','type' => 'CHAR' ],
    'price_clause' => [ 'key' => '_price', 'type' => 'NUMERIC'],
    'custom_cat_rank_clause' => [ 'key' => '_custom_cat_rank', 'type' => 'NUMERIC']
  ]);
  
    
    //https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters
    $args["orderby"] = ['stock_status_clause' => 'ASC', 'price_clause' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC', 'custom_cat_rank_clause' => 'ASC' ];
   
    return $args;

},100);
```

On certain categories and for certain products, I want to change `_custom_cat_rank` value for the product. For example - if `_custom_cat_rank` is set as 2 for a product in `wp_postmeta` table, I want it to be changed to 1 on certain category pages conditionally without having to change it in the database so that the product ranking on those category pages is modified. This will enable product ranking modification conditionally on a per product basis. How to do this?

Comment: Just dont include _custom_cat_rank as ordering ? set conditions on set_query_var and based on your logic include or exclude this from sorting ?

Comment: The question is how to set logic on a per product basis. For example - if product is A, consider `_custom_cat_rank` as 1 else consider it as 2. –